# Limit factoring

Tags: calculus, limits

I've the following limit to be calculated.

$\lim_{x \to 7} \dfrac{5 - \sqrt{4 + 3x}}{7 - x}$

I'm used to solve this limits from Calculus I text books but I've been struggling without success on this one, how make it non-indeterminable ?

Comment: sorry, I had a typo, fixed now.

Comment: Now the numerator isn't a real number near $x=7$. Do you really mean $x\rightarrow -7$?

Comment: I suspect the radicand should be $4 + 3x$, giving $\to \frac 00$

Comment: Once OP fixes the problem, he might consider L'Hopital

Comment: yes @amWhy, I had another typo, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** multiply by $$\frac{5+\sqrt{4+3x}}{5+\sqrt{4+3x}}$$ And recall that $(\alpha-\beta)(\alpha+\beta) = \alpha^2 - \beta^2$. This *trick* is called **multiplying by the conjugate**, and it is a way of getting rid of those roots and the $\frac{0}{0}$ type of indetermination.

Comment: You need + under radical ... OP edited problem. :)

Comment: You're correct indeed, wrote that right in my whiteboard though. :)

Comment: With this multiplication, the upper side will become 0.

Comment: @aajjbb How come?, the numerator goes like this: $(5-\sqrt{4+3x})(5+\sqrt{4+3x}) = 5^2 - (\sqrt{4+3x})^2 = 25 - (4+3x) = 21 - 3x = 3(7-x)$.

Comment: As x -> 7, 3(7 - x) = 0.

Comment: @aajjbb there's a $7-x$ in the denominator, too. You can _cancel them out_.

Comment: noticed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By  L'Hopital theorem we have $$\lim\limits_{x\to7}\frac{5-\sqrt{4+3x}}{7-x}=\lim\limits_{x\to7}\frac{-3}{-2\sqrt{4+3x}}=\frac{3}{10}$$